# How can a service sometimes get SSL/TLS errors

Tags: c#, ssl, service

We have this windows service running every 5 seconds or so that is able to connect and get data 99% of the time. There is some issue, which is yet to be resolved, where the service will start failing. We will get this error spammed back for minutes/hours and then the service seems to fix itself and go on getting data.

System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

I'm wondering if there is anything in the code below that could produce such a behavior. If not I'm guessing it is some issue with the server we are pinging.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

public abstract class QueryBase
{
    private const string URL = "https://whatever.com/xml/query";
    private readonly X509Certificate certificate;
    public static Cookie Session { get; set; }
    private readonly Regex sessionReg = new Regex("Session=(\\w+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    protected QueryBase(X509Certificate cert)
    {
        certificate = cert;
    }

    protected abstract string GetPostData();

    public string SubmitQuery()
    {
        string data;

        var request = CreateRequest();

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (Session == null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; i++)
                {
                    var name = response.Headers.GetKey(i);
                    if (name != "Set-Cookie") continue;
                    var value = response.Headers.Get(i);
                    var match = sessionReg.Match(value);
                    if (match.Captures.Count <= 0) continue;
                    Session = new Cookie("Session", match.Groups[1].Value, "/", "whatever.com");
                    break;
                }
            }
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    private HttpWebRequest CreateRequest()
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.UserAgent = "NOTABROWSER";

        request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

        if (Session != null)
        {
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer.Add(Session);
        }

        var xml = GetPostData();

        var xmlBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
        request.ContentLength = xmlBytes.Length;

        var s = request.GetRequestStream();
        s.Write(xmlBytes, 0, xmlBytes.Length);

        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ask the server owner? It may be load balanced and you may not hit the same instance each time. You should also compare details of the TLS handshake and the TCP level between attempts that succeed and those that do not, like IP connected to, `ServerHello` message content, where exactly does it stop working in the TLS handshake, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**It's probably the server, but could be the client certificate**

"Could not create SSL/TSL secure channel" means the connection isn't being established.  That means that you're not transmitting the actual request, or doing anything with cookies.  The client certificate [would be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532392/client-certificate-authentication-in-ssl-handshake) in establishing the connection, so if the client certificate is changing for any reason, that could be it.

Comment: I create the QueryBase on the startup of the service, which also sets the certificate. Then it is not edited or changed again so I'm doubting it could be that.